# GCP AutoML TextSnippet longer than 10.000 characters

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

I've been using the GCP AUtoML Python library version 2.2.0 for text extraction, and usually it works perfect. However sometimes it gives me this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/wr/api/simple_text_nlp.py", line 159, in extract_entity_from_text
    predict_data, predict_id, predict_error = extract_entity.predict(text, model_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ProfessorPatPending/ocr/textOperations.py", line 68, in predict
    response = self.__client.predict(name=model_path, payload=payload)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/automl_v1/services/prediction_service/client.py", line 498, in predict
    response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 145, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 75, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 List of found errors:   1.Field: payload.text_snippet.content; Message: The provided string field value is longer than 10000: 10796
```

The TextSnippet in question has more than 10.000 characters, however the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/automl/latest/automl_v1/types.html?highlight=textsni#google.cloud.automl_v1.types.TextSnippet) clearly states that it can be up until 250.000 characters. Can someone explain to me what's going on?

The code to create the text snippet is:

```
client = automl.PredictionServiceClient.from_service_account_file(sa_json_file)    
text_snippet = automl.TextSnippet(content=text_data, mime_type="text/plain")
payload = automl.ExamplePayload(text_snippet=text_snippet)
response = client.predict(name=model_path, payload=payload)
```

For obvious reasons, I won't post the `text_data` itself here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you encountered is on `client.predict()` since you are sending a TextSnippet greater than 10k characters. [AutoML Entity Extraction](https://googleapis.dev/python/automl/latest/automl_v1/services.html#google.cloud.automl_v1.services.prediction_service.PredictionServiceClient.predict) is only limited to 10k characters per prediction request.

> AutoML Natural Language Entity Extraction
>
> - A TextSnippet up to 10,000 characters, UTF-8 NFC encoded or a document in .PDF, .TIF or .TIFF format with size upto 20MB.

I suggest that you split your TextSnippet and send multiple request or trim the TextSnippet to 10k to satisfy character limit.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I'll update and see if it works.